# Insert in database the fields of 2 functions having the same combobox. Only the data of the first function is saved

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I have a database manager, made with tkinter, in which I insert and save the data. It works fine, everything correctly, it saves everything correctly. I tried adding a new insert, and this is where I have a problem. However, I cannot add a new insertion of a field from the same combobox, i.e. that the same combobox inserts 2 things. I have written 2 different functions with 2 different cursor.execute SELECT, but they save the data of only one function (combo_campionati).

I will insert only the parts of the code useful for solving the problem. How can I also save the data of the id_campionato function?
I would like to make sure that when I select the championship name from the combobox, I also get and save the ID number of the same selected championship. So: I select, for example, the name x in the combobox, then if it corresponds to the name x of Name_Campionate FROM ARCHIVE_CHAMPIONSHIP, then the ID of the championship will be taken and saved in another table

The two functions are these. The first works save correctly, the second mistakenly saves the same name as the first function combo_campionati.

```
def combo_campionati():
    campionato = combo_Campionato.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Nome_Campionato FROM ARCHIVIO_CAMPIONATI')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

#Combobox Campionati
lbl_Campionato = Label(root, text="Campionato", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#E95420", fg="white")
lbl_Campionato.place(x=6, y=60)
combo_Campionato = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, textvariable=campionato, state="readonly")
combo_Campionato.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_Campionato.set("Seleziona campionato")
combo_Campionato['values'] = combo_campionati(), 
combo_Campionato.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_squadre)


def id_campionati():
    campionato = combo_Campionato.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ID_Campionato FROM ARCHIVIO_Campionati WHERE Nome_Campionato=?',(campionato,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result
```

The problem is that to save, I use the combobox name (campionato.get) inside the function def add_employee of the "Add" button (where db.insert is). The problem is ONLY the new function def id_campionati. The problem is, I don't know how to assign a textvariable (or something similar) to sampled_id. So the saved data is the same as the campionato.get and its relative textvariable = campionato. Text variable assignment problem (or something to differentiate the name to save league and id_campionato). The name "campionato" is assigned and then saved correctly through the combobox, while the name id_campionato is not assigned and is not saved through the combobox itself

```
def add_employee():
    if combo_Campionato.get() == "" or combo_Giornate.get() == "" or  de.get() == "" or combo_Orario_Ora.get() == "" or combo_Orario_Minuti.get() == "" or combo_NomeSquadra_Casa.get() == "" or combo_NomeSquadra_Fuori.get() == "" or combo_Risultato_Sq_A.get() == "" or combo_Risultato_Sq_B.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Erorr in Input", "Please Fill All the Details")
        return
    db.insert(campionato.get(), giornata.get(), de.get(),combo_Orario_Ora.get(), combo_Orario_Minuti.get(), combo_NomeSquadra_Casa.get(), combo_NomeSquadra_Fuori.get(), combo_Risultato_Sq_A.get(), combo_Risultato_Sq_B.get(), campionato.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Record Inserted")
    clearAll()
    dispalyAll()

# Insert Function
def insert(self, campionato, giornata, calendario, ore, minuti, squadra_casa, squadra_fuori, ris_sq_casa, ris_sq_fuori, id_campionato):
        self.cur.execute("insert into ARCHIVIO_Risultati values (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                         (campionato, giornata, calendario, ore, minuti, squadra_casa, squadra_fuori, ris_sq_casa, ris_sq_fuori, id_campionato))
        self.con.commit()
```

How can I also save the data of the id_campionato function?

UPLOAD
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this really  your actual code? `def insert` appears indented inside `add_employee`. It's not clear if you think `db.insert(...)` is calling this insert function or some other function. I think you've asked this question at least three times, each time with just fragments of code. If you expect to get help, you should provide a runnable [mcve], preferably without any GUI code. Start by writing a complete little program that tries to insert the data via a function. Once the function works, plugging it into the GUI should be very easy.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was wrong in copying and pasting here on StackOverflow: def insert did not fit inside add_employee. def insert is something else. And you answered me 3 times saying to redo the program again: it is complete and working. It is useless to write a new one if it already works now. It already enters the data correctly through some functions. The problem is ONLY the new function def id_campionati. The problem is, I don't know how to assign a textvariable (or something similar) to sampled_id. So the saved data is the same as the campionato.get and its relative textvariable = campionato

Comment: @BryanOakley COMMENT # 2: I know how to insert new data through the function, but I don't know how to insert 2 different data through the same combobox, due to problems of assigning the textvariable (or something to differentiate the name to be saved of league and id_campionato. The name "campionato" is assigned and then it is saved correctly through the combobox, while the name id_campionato is not assigned and it is not saved through the combobox itself. Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: _"The problem is ONLY the new function def id_campionati."_ - then please write a new program that has only that function, and enough extra code to make it work. Based on what you've said, all of the other code is completely irrelevant to the question being asked. The bottom line is that this problem is hard to understand, and I think part of that is due to the fact we can't actually run the code to see the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I haven't written a program that only has that function. THE PROGRAM WORKS GOOD. You're making a controversy, you're being a professor, you're pointing out unimportant things, and you can't solve a simple enough problem. I am just starting out with Python, but I can understand that the problem with the error in inserting id_campionato is that it does not have an assignment that can be called into db.insert.

Comment: I'm not making a controversy. The purpose of a [mcve] is to distill the problem down to the smallest amount of code possible. Often, the mere process of doing so will teach you where the problem is. This is a very common technique that software developers use all the time.

Comment: _"the problem with the error in inserting id_campionato is that it does not have an assignment that can be called into db.insert. " - I do not know what you mean by that. You seem to have a function that returns a value. When you call `id_campionati` it returns a list of zero of more ids. Why can't you call this function, and then use the results when inserting into the database? That part is not clear.

Comment: @BryanOakley "Why can't you call this function and then use the results when inserting into the database? That part isn't clear." So that's what I'm wrong. Thanks for acknowledging it. I'm in the early days of Python. Could you show me how could I please solve? Of course I will vote for your answer and assign the question as resolved. Thanks

Comment: After all of this, are you saying the problem boils down to you not knowing how to call a function and use the return value?

Comment: Also, your description and some comments mentions needing to use `sampled_id` but you haven't defined that anywhere in the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley Obviously I know how to recall a function. Let's not joke. I don't know if it all comes down to calling a function. But I don't know how to recall it in db.insert, or rather, I don't know if it is possible to recall it directly in db.insert. Anyway I said I'm just starting out with Python. Sorry for sample_id, it means id_campionato: the Google translator translates badly. Could you show me the code of how I can solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I have no idea what you're asking since you haven't produced an example we can run. You seem to have a function named `insert` that works, except that it needs to save an extra value. You claim to have a function that gets the value which should be saved. So, the solution seems to be to call the function, save the result, and then pass it to the function that writes it to the database.

```
def add_employee():
    ...
    id_campionati_value = id_campionati()
    db.insert(campionato.get(), ..., id_campionati_value)
```

I doubt it will work exactly like that since `id_campionati()` returns a list rather than a single value. You should probably rewrite `id_campionati_value` to return a single id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are very nice. I am getting this error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. I want to use the id of each campionato. I want to obtain that: when I click on Insert, a row is saved in which I have various data, including the id for each campionato selected in the combobox. For example, I select the Serie A championship (campionato) from the combobox, and automatically the ID of the Serie A championship is taken and saved. I CHANGED THE QUESTION BY INSERTING 2 SCREENSHOTS, SO YOU CAN UNDERSTAND BETTER. What else can I do? Thanks

Comment: I add this to the previous comment where I quote the screenshots: how should I rewrite id_campionato_value and to return a single id? Can you show me please? Thanks a lot and sorry

Comment: Basically, if in the combo_Campionato combobox I select a specific team (extracts the names from the ARCHIVIO_CAMPIONATI table), I would like to obtain the Id_Campionato of the relative same selected team (always extracted from the same ARCHIVIO_CAMPIONATI table as you can see in the two screenshots). The ID, however, will automatically insert itself in another new table of the database together with other fields, thanks to db.insert, to form records for relational purposes with the Foreign Key.